# how to write a program that will take a number and check if it is divisible by 5 or not by not dividing the number by 5 (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code I have to take an input from the user and say if the input is divisible by 5 or not, **but with out using the code** `user % 5 == 0`

Comment: Are you allowed `n=5 ... user%n==0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main() :
 x = int(input("enter the number"))
 if x // 5 * 5 == x :
    print("yes")
 else:
    print("no")
main()
```

This worked

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
def f(x):
  return (x % 10) in (0, 5)
```

Or this:

```
def g(x):
  return x == x // 5 * 5
```

Or this slow one:

```
def h(x):
  if x < 0:
    x = -x
  while x >= 5:
    x -= 5
  return x == 0
```

Or this (also slow, but faster than h):

```
def i(x):
  return str(x)[-1] in '05'
```

Or this:

```
def j(x):
  return str(x << 1).endswith('0')
```

There are many more solutions.

Comment: can you suggest me some more solutions to this problem

Comment: Sure, I've added i(x).

Comment: i think i(x) is much better solution(,just check last digit is 0 or 5 ) compare to other where we have to calculate,

Comment: you should check division by 0 !

Comment: @AlexandreB.: I think all the functions in my answer are correct for all int values, without additional checks. Do you have an example input where any of my functions fail?

Comment: @prashantrana: It's impossible to say which solution is best without specifying what we want to optimize for. For example, f(x) is faster than i(x).

Comment: @pts Sorry I spoke to fast !

Answer (score 1):

```
t = int(input())
print(t/5==t//5)
```

or use

```
def f(x):
    return (t/5==t//5)
```

this will return true or false if the number is divisible by 5 or not.

PS. as pointed by @Pts this code is valid upto certain length of number(10^15) ,if number is too large floating point error come.

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) indicates that 64-bit floats have 53-bit precisions, so numbers t whose absolute value is smaller than 2 ** 53 will work, others may fail

Comment: This code is incorrect, for example if t is 1180591620717411303425, then it prints False, but the correct result would be True. The incorrectness is caused by floating point rounding errors in the operation `/`.

Comment: A simpler example when this code prints False (incorrect): if t is 1000000000000000000000000.

Comment: @pts i guess it will correct upto 10^15 digit. , after that it fails

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats indicates that 64-bit floats have 53-bit precision, so numbers t whose absolute value is smaller than `2 ** 53` will work, others may fail.

Answer (score 0):

I naturally think of something like this:

```
def divisible(user, x):
    if (x > user or x <= 0):
        return False
    while (user > 0):
            user -= x
    return user == 0
```

Don't forget to check if `x` is **negative** and **lower than user**

Comment: this is taking so much time for large number divisible(1180591620717411303425,5)